# HTTP Header User-Agent Field Format Required?

Tags: http-headers, rfc

I could not find anything in the RFC docs about whether the User-Agent field needed to be formatted the way it commonly is. For example, could I just do:

User-Agent: Mozilla windows NT

and still pass a valid request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal definition of the `User-Agent` header is defined in [RFC 2616 Section 14.43](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43) as follows:

```
User-Agent     = "User-Agent" ":" 1*( product | comment )
```

`product` is defined in [Section 3.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.8) as follows:

```
product         = token ["/" product-version]
product-version = token
```

`token` and `comment` are defined in [Section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2) as follows:

```
token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
comment        = "(" *( ctext | quoted-pair | comment ) ")"
```

Whitespace is a separator, so to answer your question, `Mozilla windows NT` is NOT a valid product by the above `token` definition.  If you want to follow the spec, you could instead format it more like this: `Mozilla (Windows NT)`.

Comment: What if I did Mozilla ((windows NT)), or something derivative. I'm guessing this would be invalid, as parenthesis are key characters here?

Comment: Look at the definitions. A `comment` is delimited by parenthesis, and a `comment` can contain another `comment`, thus parenthesis are nestable. So what do you think `((windows NT))` means?  A nested comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can 'fake' a user agent. Check for yourself with this tool for instance: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Comment: I understand that you can fake a user agent, but this is still keeping the format of the user-agent to the RFC standard. I'm asking whether you can ignore the standard (standard is stated as name of application (comments) )